# interacting with SPM preprocessing using MATLAB batch script

Tags: matlab

I am having a problem with a script that is supposed to batch a preprocessing pipeline for fMRI data. The problem itself is not imaging related, but rather some sort of coding problem that I cannot resolve, no matter how many iterations of a solution I have tried to put together.

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% MATLAB Preprocessing Script


    spm_jobman('initcfg');
    spm('defaults','FMRI');
    spm_jobman('run', matlabbatch);


    gender = { 'female' };
    subjs = { 'sub_06' 'sub_07' };
    subjs_xt = { 'SUB_006' 'SUB_007' };



%% SPM Preprocessing
for k = 1:length(subjs)


    matlabbatch{1}.spm.temporal.st.scans = {
        {
        'Z:\subject_data\' gender '\' subjs{k} '\Functional\' subjs_xt{k} '_run_1\run_1-t000-0001.nii,1'
...
        'Z:\subject_data\' gender '\' subjs{k} '\Functional\' subjs_xt{k} '_run_1\run_1-t000-0132.nii,1'
        }
        }';
    %%
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.temporal.st.nslices = 30;
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.temporal.st.tr = 2;
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.temporal.st.ta = 1.93333333333333;
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.temporal.st.so = [1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30];
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.temporal.st.refslice = 1;
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.temporal.st.prefix = 'a';
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.data{1}(1) = cfg_dep('Slice Timing: Slice Timing Corr. Images (Sess 1)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{1}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.data{2}(1) = cfg_dep('Slice Timing: Slice Timing Corr. Images (Sess 2)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{2}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.data{3}(1) = cfg_dep('Slice Timing: Slice Timing Corr. Images (Sess 3)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{3}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.data{4}(1) = cfg_dep('Slice Timing: Slice Timing Corr. Images (Sess 4)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{4}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.eoptions.quality = 0.9;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.eoptions.sep = 4;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.eoptions.fwhm = 5;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.eoptions.rtm = 1;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.eoptions.interp = 2;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.eoptions.wrap = [0 0 0];
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.eoptions.weight = '';
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.roptions.which = [0 1];
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.roptions.interp = 4;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.roptions.wrap = [0 0 0];
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.roptions.mask = 1;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.spatial.realign.estwrite.roptions.prefix = 'r';
    matlabbatch{3}.spm.spatial.coreg.estimate.ref(1) = cfg_dep('Realign: Estimate & Reslice: Mean Image', substruct('.','val', '{}',{2}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','rmean'));
    matlabbatch{3}.spm.spatial.coreg.estimate.source = {'Z:\subject_data\' gender '\' subjs{k} '\Structural\T1-0001.nii,1'};
    matlabbatch{3}.spm.spatial.coreg.estimate.other = {''};
    matlabbatch{3}.spm.spatial.coreg.estimate.eoptions.cost_fun = 'nmi';
    matlabbatch{3}.spm.spatial.coreg.estimate.eoptions.sep = [4 2];
    matlabbatch{3}.spm.spatial.coreg.estimate.eoptions.tol = [0.02 0.02 0.02 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.001 0.001 0.001];
    matlabbatch{3}.spm.spatial.coreg.estimate.eoptions.fwhm = [7 7];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.channel.vols(1) = cfg_dep('Coregister: Estimate: Coregistered Images', substruct('.','val', '{}',{3}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','cfiles'));
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.channel.biasreg = 0.001;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.channel.biasfwhm = 60;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.channel.write = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(1).tpm = {'C:\Program Files\spm12\spm12\tpm\TPM.nii,1'};
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(1).ngaus = 1;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(1).native = [1 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(1).warped = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(2).tpm = {'C:\Program Files\spm12\spm12\tpm\TPM.nii,2'};
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(2).ngaus = 1;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(2).native = [1 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(2).warped = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(3).tpm = {'C:\Program Files\spm12\spm12\tpm\TPM.nii,3'};
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(3).ngaus = 2;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(3).native = [1 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(3).warped = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(4).tpm = {'C:\Program Files\spm12\spm12\tpm\TPM.nii,4'};
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(4).ngaus = 3;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(4).native = [1 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(4).warped = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(5).tpm = {'C:\Program Files\spm12\spm12\tpm\TPM.nii,5'};
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(5).ngaus = 4;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(5).native = [1 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(5).warped = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(6).tpm = {'C:\Program Files\spm12\spm12\tpm\TPM.nii,6'};
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(6).ngaus = 2;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(6).native = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.tissue(6).warped = [0 0];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.warp.mrf = 1;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.warp.cleanup = 1;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.warp.reg = [0 0.001 0.5 0.05 0.2];
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.warp.affreg = 'mni';
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.warp.fwhm = 0;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.warp.samp = 3;
    matlabbatch{4}.spm.spatial.preproc.warp.write = [0 1];
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(1).def(1) = cfg_dep('Segment: Forward Deformations', substruct('.','val', '{}',{4}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','fordef', '()',{':'}));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(1).resample(1) = cfg_dep('Realign: Estimate & Reslice: Realigned Images (Sess 1)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{2}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','sess', '()',{1}, '.','cfiles'));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(2).def(1) = cfg_dep('Segment: Forward Deformations', substruct('.','val', '{}',{4}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','fordef', '()',{':'}));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(2).resample(1) = cfg_dep('Realign: Estimate & Reslice: Realigned Images (Sess 2)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{2}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','sess', '()',{2}, '.','cfiles'));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(3).def(1) = cfg_dep('Segment: Forward Deformations', substruct('.','val', '{}',{4}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','fordef', '()',{':'}));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(3).resample(1) = cfg_dep('Realign: Estimate & Reslice: Realigned Images (Sess 3)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{2}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','sess', '()',{3}, '.','cfiles'));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(4).def(1) = cfg_dep('Segment: Forward Deformations', substruct('.','val', '{}',{4}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','fordef', '()',{':'}));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.subj(4).resample(1) = cfg_dep('Realign: Estimate & Reslice: Realigned Images (Sess 4)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{2}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('.','sess', '()',{4}, '.','cfiles'));
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.woptions.bb = [-78 -112 -70
        78 76 85];
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.woptions.vox = [2 2 2];
    matlabbatch{5}.spm.spatial.normalise.write.woptions.interp = 4;
    matlabbatch{6}.spm.spatial.smooth.data(1) = cfg_dep('Normalise: Write: Normalised Images (Subj 1)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{5}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{1}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{6}.spm.spatial.smooth.fwhm = [8 8 8];
    matlabbatch{6}.spm.spatial.smooth.dtype = 0;
    matlabbatch{6}.spm.spatial.smooth.im = 0;
    matlabbatch{6}.spm.spatial.smooth.prefix = 's';
    matlabbatch{7}.spm.spatial.smooth.data(1) = cfg_dep('Normalise: Write: Normalised Images (Subj 2)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{5}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{2}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{7}.spm.spatial.smooth.fwhm = [8 8 8];
    matlabbatch{7}.spm.spatial.smooth.dtype = 0;
    matlabbatch{7}.spm.spatial.smooth.im = 0;
    matlabbatch{7}.spm.spatial.smooth.prefix = 's';
    matlabbatch{8}.spm.spatial.smooth.data(1) = cfg_dep('Normalise: Write: Normalised Images (Subj 3)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{5}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{3}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{8}.spm.spatial.smooth.fwhm = [8 8 8];
    matlabbatch{8}.spm.spatial.smooth.dtype = 0;
    matlabbatch{8}.spm.spatial.smooth.im = 0;
    matlabbatch{8}.spm.spatial.smooth.prefix = 's';
    matlabbatch{9}.spm.spatial.smooth.data(1) = cfg_dep('Normalise: Write: Normalised Images (Subj 4)', substruct('.','val', '{}',{5}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}, '.','val', '{}',{1}), substruct('()',{4}, '.','files'));
    matlabbatch{9}.spm.spatial.smooth.fwhm = [8 8 8];
    matlabbatch{9}.spm.spatial.smooth.dtype = 0;
    matlabbatch{9}.spm.spatial.smooth.im = 0;
    matlabbatch{9}.spm.spatial.smooth.prefix = 's';

end
```

The code is obviously pretty long, but that is because I am trying to get it to work with 132 files for each functional run. I have been able to make this work with 1 file per run, but that is not sufficient.

The error I am receiving is:

```
 ??? Undefined function or variable 'matlabbatch'.

Error in ==> batch_preprocessing_old at 17
    spm_jobman('run', matlabbatch);
```

Any help on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you familiar with matlab? Anyway, your syntax is fine, but you need a variable named `matlabbatch` with proper fields to run this. Examples I found online call `load toy_batch` as an example, which provides such a variable... Any more details perhaps on your problem?

Comment: When I do that I get the following error:

`Warning: Unknown extension: 'matlabbatch' 
> In spm_jobman>load_jobs at 347
  In spm_jobman at 142
  In batch_preprocessing_old at 17
Warning: No batch job found in 'matlabbatch' 
> In spm_jobman>load_jobs at 356
  In spm_jobman at 142
  In batch_preprocessing_old at 17
??? Error using ==> spm_jobman at 245
No valid job.

Error in ==> batch_preprocessing_old at 17`

I wish I knew more about what spm_jobman was doing so I could offer more input... The literature on spm batching in this way is scarce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matlab-related problem is that your script references a variable named `matlabbatch` without having defined it. If this is really a matlab *script*, and not part of a function, then you should `load` this variable earlier (from a `.mat` file) to have it in your base workspace, or construct it in some other way.

The act of producing a valid `matlabbatch` is `spm`-related. Have a look at [the manual](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/doc/manual.pdf) if you haven't done so. Section 39.1.4 *Automatisation of preprocessing* seems to describe what to do. If not there, somewhere earlier in the manual. As this assumes familiarity with `spm` itself, I didn't try to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this a bit late, and while probably not still relevant to the OP, I thought I would offer an answer in case someone else runs across this. The problem is likely that the call to spm_jobman at line 17 spm_jobman('run', matlabbatch) is written prior to defining matlabbatch. There is no need to load a prior .mat file; the code offered should define matlabbatch properly with the structure intact. You just can't call spm_jobman to run it until after the declarations are made. Move that line to the bottom of the script.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is not an SPM-related problem, but a simple programming error.